# Loop through array and append inside <ul> as <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I want the out put to be like this.
[image] When i loop through the  array object i am getting the out put like this.where the First LI tags gets appeneded to the Next LI tags.
Here is my array output:

```
Object { AUSTRALIA: "http://au.com# AU,http://mcg.com# MCG", INDIA: "http://kp.com# KP,http://ap.com# AP,http://tg.com# TG", PAKISTAN: "http://PK.COM# PK,http://POL# POL", USA: "http://UU# UU,http://PHL.com# PHL" }.
```

Below is the code for the same.

```
for (var category in clientData)
                     {
                         var category_attr;
                         category_attr = clientData[category];
                         category_attr = category_attr.split(",");

                          html = "<ul>" + category.trim() + "</ul>";
                         for(var i=0; i<category_attr.length; i++)
                         {
                             var temp = category_attr[i].split("#");
                             var url = temp[0].trim();
                             var urldesc = temp[1].trim();
                              liHtml += "<li>"+
                                     "<a href='" +url +"'>"+urldesc+""+"</a>"+
                                  "</li>";  
                         }
                         html = html + liHtml;
                         $("#tasksUL").append(html);
                     }
                       //$("#tasksUL").append(html); 
                    }
        });

}
</script>
<div id="tasksUL" ></div>
```

Output Imagec
[image]

Comment: *"When i loop through the JSON array object..."* If you're looping through it, it's not JSON. JSON is a **textual notation**. If you're looping through it, it's just an array, nothing whatsoever to do with JSON.

Comment: Thanks TJ. So can i loop through the array and assign it to UL and LI

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this like below

```
   for (var category in clientData)
                         {
                             var category_attr = [];
                            // console.log(category);
                             category_attr = clientData[category];
                             category_attr = category_attr.split(",");
                            // console.log(category_attr);
                              html = "<div style='float: left'><ul><li class='list-view'>" + category.trim() + "</li>";
                             liHtml = "";
                             for(var i=0; i<category_attr.length; i++)
                             {
                                 var temp = category_attr[i].split("#");
                                 var url = temp[0].trim();
                                 var urldesc = temp[1].trim();
                                  liHtml += "<li>"+
                                         "<a href='" +url +"'>"+urldesc+""+"</a>"+
                                      "</li>";  
                             }
                             html = html + liHtml + "</ul></div>";
                             $("#tasksUL").append(html);
                         }

                        }
<style type="text/css" >    
#tasksUL ul{  width:350px;  }
#tasksUL ul li{ list-style: inside none square !important; padding-left:10px !important;   }
.list-view { background: #005898 !important; padding:2px; color:#FFF !important;   }
</style>
<div id="tasksUL" ></div>
```